# Set the selected option by value in the Kendo DropDownList

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

I have a kendo ui dropdownlist with angularjs in my html:

```
<select kendo-drop-down-list="dropdownlistCatalogs" k-options="optionsDropDownListCatalogs" data-role="dropdownlist" style="display: none;">
   <option value="2" selected="selected">Test1</option>
   <option value="3">Test2</option>
   <option value="4">Test3</option>
</select>
```

In the angularjs controller, everytime i click on an item in the dropdownlist, i call this function to remove the selected item from the dropdown control:

```
function removeItemFromDropDown(e) {
   var index = e.item.index();
   var selectedItem = $scope.dropdownlistCatalogs.dataItem(e.item.index());
   $scope.optionsDropDownListCatalogs.dataSource.remove(selectedItem);
}
```

Now, i want set the selected option to non existing item to show an empty value.

I have tried with:

```
$scope.dropdownlistCatalogs.value(-1);
```

but not working

How can i set the dropdownlist by value()?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure much about angularjs and if things are different. I see `$scope` in there which I guess is of angular, since i dont see it defined anywhere. But Usually `value` will help you with this if using jquery

Add a default blank value at the top with `id:-1` and set the default value as 1.

On click of a button, you can change the value to -1

It would look like this :

```
var data = [
    { "text": "" , id: -1 }, 
    { "text": "aaa",id: 1 },
    { "text": "bbb",id: 2 },
    { "text": "ccc", id:3}
];

$("#ddl").kendoDropDownList({
    dataTextField: "text",
    dataValueField: "id",
    dataSource: data,
    index: 3
});

$("#button").on("click", function ()  {

    var dropdownlist = $("#ddl").data("kendoDropDownList");

    dropdownlist.value(-1);
});
```

[Here is an working example](http://jsfiddle.net/mRmNJ/342/)